# Нужна ли сборка мусора в C?

Tags: c

Я ничего не нашел про сборку мусора в C. Нужна ли она? Как её сделать? Или все же мусор исчезает сам?

Comment: В С выделяете память и освобождаете ее вы сами. Тут просто нет никакого мусора :)

Comment: @Harry from Kiev с помощью функций malloc и free?

Comment: Да, malloc и free. Сюда ещё можно дописать tealloc и calloc

Comment: Есть [такое](https://hboehm.info/gc/)

Comment: В с++ уборка мусора есть, причем с минимальными накладными расходами. Называется raii

Comment: @KoVadim, подскажите, нужно все очищать, или только со структур.

Comment: все, все что выделяется через malloc/calloc(который внутри вызывает maloc)/realloc нужно явно освобождать через free. И не важно, что там - структуры или массивы. strdup тоже вызывает внутри malloc, так что после него тоже нужно освобождать. Если ресурсы выделяются другим средствами, то нужно искать парные функции. К примеру, fopen - fclose.

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо вам